# Javascript plugin needs to call back to client's Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on a plugin that allows to add an item to the shopping cart. The plugin is mine, and the shopping cart belongs to the customer. The idea is to add my plugin with a few lines of code to configure. 
Once an item is bought, I need to call a function on the customer page so it can be added to the cart, but I didn't manage.
I have this code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function () {

  //plugin1.CallBackTest;
 });

 var plugin1 = new function() {

  this.CallBackTest = function (str) {
   console.log("callback in class");
   FunctionIWantToCall(str);
  }
 }

 function FunctionIWantToCall(str) {
  console.log("callback on client " + str);
 }

  

</script>


<div class="htmlcreatedbyplugin">
 <button onclick="CallBackTest('something')">send back</button>
</div>
```

if I change this line to 
send back
it will work, but this html is generated through the plugin class, and I don't know how to retrieve the name of the variable. 
The customer should be able to tell the plugin which function to call, e.g
plugin1.AddToCartFunction = FunctionIWantToCall;
Any ideas?

Comment: I find your explanation a little confusing so I'm not sure I'm on the right track here, that's why I'm commenting instead of answering.  I would capture the whole click event by jquery : $(document).on("click", ". htmlcreatedbyplugin > button", function() {}); Then I would pass the variables I need as data attributes or hidden inputs for my function to find in the DOM. If this is on the right track and you can make what you want more clear to me I will right a better a more complete answer.

Comment: That could work, there are of course many buttons (one for each product), but that shouldn't be a problem I think and I can use data attributes for the values.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Stavros Angelis, it works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        plugin1.CallBackFunction = "FunctionIWantToCall";
    });

    var plugin1 = new function () {
        var myplugin = this;
        this.CallBackFunction = "";

        this.CallBackTest = function () {
            console.log("callback in class");

            var item = JSON.parse($(this).attr("vals"));
            if (myplugin.CallBackFunction != "") {
                window[myplugin.CallBackFunction](item);
            }
        }

        function BindCartButtons() {
            console.log("binding buttons")
            $(document).on("click", ".htmlcreatedbyplugin > button", myplugin.CallBackTest);
        }

        BindCartButtons();
    }

    function FunctionIWantToCall(item) {
        console.log("callback on client " + item.id);
    }
</script>


<div class="htmlcreatedbyplugin">
    <button type="button" vals="{&#34;id&#34;:12345, &#34;color&#34;:&#34;blue&#34;}">Buy Me</button>
</div>
```